# finding the minimum value using vb net code

Tags: vb.net

I write a code using vb.net to find a minimum value from values entered in a input box. But it gives an error.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim xMinNo, y As Integer
    Dim xTemp As Integer
    Dim i, x As Integer

    x = CInt(InputBox("Please Enter Number of subjects"))
    For i = 1 To x
        xTemp = InputBox("enter Mark: ")
        If xMinNo < xTemp Then
            xMinNo = xTemp
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox("The Lowest Number is " & xMinNo)
End Sub
```

Since xMin is intially 0 it shows that value. Please help me to over come that issue

Comment: It is the opposite: *if xTemp < xMinNo then xMinNo = xTemp*. Set *xMinNo* initially not to zero but to a very large value, maybe the largest positive int

Comment: How it can do. I try but fail

Comment: "It gives an error" is not a suitable problem description. You didn't even tell us what the error is.

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the user enters a # less than 1 for the # of subjects?

Answer (score 1):

You really would want to add data validation as well to ensure they are entering numbers.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim xMinNo, y As Integer
    Dim xTemp As Integer
    Dim i, x As Integer

    x = CInt(InputBox("Please Enter Number of subjects"))
    For i = 1 To x
        xTemp = InputBox("enter Mark: ")
        If i = 1 Then
           xMinNo = xTemp
        End If

        If xMinNo > xTemp Then
            xMinNo = xTemp
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox("The Lowest Number is " & xMinNo)
End Sub
```